# changing shape of object of a variable, making object property optional

Tags: typescript

```
let myObj = {
    a: {
        value: 1
    },
    b: {
        value: 2
    }
}

myObj = { // how to make b optional?
    a: {
        value: 123
    }
}
```

is it possible to make myObj.b optional without giving it my own type?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtgng8gIwFYQLwQN4CgK4gQwC5Mc8yA3fYAVxGIEZTcBfAGiYgWOzIqtuIAmDsyyissRCnQYIAejkQAFgHsA7hDAro+ANYhOEFQAcwASxUA7KgH4ORErzyUadCPUEBmEWKxYgA

Comment: "*without giving it my own type*" why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a `type` for `myObj` with `b` optional:

```
type ObjectType = {
  a: {
    value: number
  },
  b?: {
    value: number
  }
}
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AFXNAvFA3gKCigEMAuPQoqAN2IBsBXCcgOwYFs4IAnSgXwA0lOAH5yBKjXpNWHLryJ98S-HQjAo7EPATkdKdJig4JVMhUmTajZlACMlRUMlxxjy9ZlQATO6UqtHWMLMzdLKk9bO28AZj9lIA) to a playground.